# Wordpress custom contribution and newsletter signup forms

Tags: wordpress, api, forms, custom-templates

How customizable are the contribution forms? I have created a standard contribution page from the CiviCRM plugin, but I would like to hammer it into a very stylized design.

Alternatively, is it possible to create a 100% custom form and communicate with the CiviCRM contribution backend via some API?

Comment: I watched [this overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vy62VwKm9E) of the CiviCRM API and discovered there are Javascript bindings! Looking at the API explorer, I found the `ContributionPage` entity, which exposes fields that look exactly like the default form. I created a test JSON params and submitted it using the console on a dummy contribution page and succeeded creating a credit card contribution through the dummy processor!  My plan now is to create a theme javascript file to include on the contribution page that does the same thing based on custom form values. Is this nuts?